# WebApi Controller no action was found for the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

A real head-scrather this one.  I have created two ApiControllers which I am using as a JSON webservice:-

```
namespace ControlTower.Controllers
{
    public class AirlinesController : ApiController
    {
        private static IEnumerable<Airline> MapAirlines()
        {
            return (Jetstream.AirlineObject.GetAirlines()).Select(x => x);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Airline> GetAirlines()
        {
            return MapAirlines().AsEnumerable();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Airline GetAirlineByCode(string code)
        {
            return Jetstream.AirlineObject.GetAirline(code);
        }
    }
}
```

and:-

```
namespace ControlTower.Controllers
{
    public class ReviewsController : ApiController
    {
        private static IEnumerable<Review> MapReviews(int airline)
        {
            return (Jetstream.ReviewObject.GetReviews(airline)).Select(x => x);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Review> GetReviews(int airline)
        {
            return MapReviews(airline).AsEnumerable();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Review GetReviewById(int review)
        {
            return Jetstream.ReviewObject.GetReview(review);
        }
    }
}
```

With this routing:-

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/get/{code}",
                defaults: new { code = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And whilst visiting `/api/airline/get/ba` or `/api/airline/get/` works perfectly, visiting any variation of **Review** does not.  Can anyone see anything really obvious I'm missing here?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the exact urls what you are using and also the error message and stacktrace if there is any? Guess: you are not sending in an airline or review and `int` is value type it must have a value. Change them to `int?`

Comment: I have tried the following URIs: `/api/reviews/get/ba`, `/api/reviews/get/`, `/api/reviews/get/1` ... I always get the same output:-

`{
$id: "1",
Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:88/ControlTower/api/reviews/get/1'.",
MessageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Reviews' that matches the request."
}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your default route is expecting a parameter named "code".  You either need to add a route to accept a parameter named airline and/or review, or explicitly tell the controller the name of the parameter.

ex. /api/reviews/get?airline=1